# early stopping for ensemble method

Tags: random-forest

1: If there is an overfitting risk in the ensemble technique whether random forest or boosting method, we can use the early stopping hyper parameter so that we can stop training if we feel like there is overfitting in the training set?

2. For random forest, we can still have overfitting if we have too many complex trees. Then, even if there is an act of averaging predictions, we cannot be free from overfitting. If we have less complex trees and some complex trees, then the predictions would be fine because of the act of averaging. Is that what I should have in mind at a high level?